# Flutter platfrom channel gives IllegalStateException on calling a aar intent

Tags: java, flutter, flutter-platform-channel

I am trying to integrate a third party native SDK(written in java) to flutter using Platfrom channeling. Now The third party sdk is perfectly working in native coding (without flutter).

But when I try to launch the intent using the platform channeling, the app just stops on button click with this error log.

```
Process: com.example.platform_view_java, PID: 27183
E/AndroidRuntime(27183): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.platform_view_java/com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3616)
E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3780)
E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2251)
E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8063)
E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
E/AndroidRuntime(27183): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:846)
E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:809)
E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at com.karza.aadhaarsdk.AadharActivity.onCreate(AadharActivity.java:115)
E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8006)
E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7990)
E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3589)
E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    ... 11 more
I/Process (27183): Sending signal. PID: 27183 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```

Here is my Native UI code:

```
class NativeView implements PlatformView{
    private  Button button;

    NativeView(Context context, int id, Map<String, Object> creationParams) {
        button = new Button(context);

        button.setText("Update");
        button.setTextSize(20);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                start_service(v);
            }
        });
    }

    public Boolean start_service(View view){
//        Log.d("NATIVE","Method called");
//        return true;
        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),com.xxx.xxx.xxx.class);
        intent.putExtra("MY-TOKEN","mytoken");
        intent.putExtra("CLIENT","xxx-xxxx");
        intent.putExtra("ENV","test");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView() {
        return button;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {}
}
```

Here is my main.dart code

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp( home: Native() );
}

class Native extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded( child: AndroidView(viewType: "view1",) ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the mainactivity.java file

```
package com.example.platform_view_java;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
        flutterEngine
                .getPlatformViewsController()
                .getRegistry()
                .registerViewFactory("view1", new NativeViewFactory());


    }
}
```

Finally My nativeviewfactory.java

```
package com.example.platform_view_java;

import android.content.Context;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import java.util.Map;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMessageCodec;
import io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformView;
import io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewFactory;

class NativeViewFactory extends PlatformViewFactory {

    NativeViewFactory() {
        super(StandardMessageCodec.INSTANCE);
    }

    @Override
    public PlatformView create(@NonNull Context context, int id, @Nullable Object args) {
        final Map<String, Object> creationParams = (Map<String, Object>) args;
        return new NativeView(context, id, creationParams);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.